# jQuery Sliding Toggle & Tab

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm trying to get the Toggle Tab to slide with the content, I currently have this working but it jumps instead of sliding with the content.

Here is my coding:

```
$('#fp_thumbtoggle').click(function() {
  $('#fp_thumbtoggle').toggleClass("active");
  $('.dropgallery').slideToggle('500');
  return false;
 });
```

You'll know what I mean if you have a quick look at this http://www.media21a.co.uk/development/fullthrottle/

Any help would be great : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to remove the `top: 65px` from the .active CSS. You may have to play around with this.

```
$('#fp_thumbtoggle').click(function() {
    $('#fp_thumbtoggle').toggleClass("active");

    if ($('#fp_thumbtoggle').hasClass('active')){
        $('#fp_thumbtoggle').animate({top:'185px'});
    }else{
        $('#fp_thumbtoggle').animate({top:'65px'});
    }
    $('.dropgallery').slideToggle('500');
    return false;
});
```